# Finding min s-t cut of network with flow on the nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs, network-flow

Given a network with flow on the nodes. How can we find min s-t cut in a network with flow on the nodes?

We know how to find min s-t cut whenever there’s a network with flow on the edges (Ford Fulkerson, Edmonds Karp)

Comment: This sounds like homework, what did you try to do?  I don't think the correct question is "with flow on the nodes".  Are you sure you're not supposed to find a minimum vertex separator?  If so, you can model each node as an edge.

Comment: This is a small part of our final project in our B.sc Computer Science degree. We are given a graph (network) that every node has a capacity (the nodes, not the edges), and we need to find a min s-t cut on that graph. 
We've found a reduction that somehow managed to do it but we didn't understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Given a directed graph, you can construct a new graph $G'$ where you replace each vertex $v$ with two vertices $v_{\text{in}}$ and $v_{\text{out}}$.  Then you add the edge $v_{\text{in}}v_{\text{out}}$ with capacity equal $v$'s capacity in $G$.  Then for each edge $vu$ in $G$, you add the edge $u_{\text{out}}v_{\text{in}}$ with capacity $+\infty$.

Let $C$ be any set of vertices in $G$ and $C'$ the corresponding *edges* in $G'$.  Then the cost of $C$ and $C'$ is the same, and $C$ is an $s$-$t$-separator if and only if $C'$ is as $s$-$t$-cut.